# Is mp3 transfer for Windows iTunes / iPhone 4s slow?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-transfer, mp3

I'm about to buy iPhone 4S, I'm curious about how fast is mp3 transfer (since I like a lot of music). And I'm using Windows. Is it a LOT slower than common direct USB transfer like on mp3 devices or is it "ok" speed?

And I'm using my own mp3s I have on my HDD.

Answer (score 2):

Speed is not an issue between iTunes and an iPhone. You can copy gigabytes of data (music, film,...) within minutes, just like with a standard USB-to-desktop connection on Windows or Mac.

Major advantage: the synchronisation makes it even faster if you only change a part of your music: it only copies the ones that you added for the first time: no more duplicates!

Comment: Awesome, and does music then have subfolders when you drag&drop a main folder folder (band discography)?

Comment: You can add music by: playlist (which can be also automatically generated via some user-friendly rules like "the last 50 songs played"), artist, album, genre... basically anything you could think of.

Comment: So I'll have to create a playlist of 30 gbs of music? :/

Comment: Per drag&drop, a matter of seconds/few minutes...

Comment: But will be sorted by folder structure?

Comment: iTunes is licence-free so I wuold advise you to give it a try even without iPhone, just to see how it deals with your music: when importing a large quantity, there is an option in iTunes to either copy all the files to the internal library (doubling the space required during import, but after that you can delete your original folder), or to just create links to your current folder. Just play with it, start with just a standard album, or an artist, and see how the import works.